# Insert sdf at coordinates

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to insert an sdf file at specific coordinates in Gazebo? For instance the origin? All I can seem to do is select my model from the insert tab and then manually place it in the viewport.

I'm new to Gazebo so my understanding of how to properly use it is still forming.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20164/insert-sdf-at-coordinates/) by [jc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6174/jc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should be able to add a model in your world file, with code similar to this:

```
<world>
...
    <include>
        <uri>model://my_model</uri>
        <pose>2.5 1.5 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
</world>
```

Where the numbers represents the global pose and orientation.

---

Originally posted by [mpc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2746/mpc/) with karma: 76 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6174/jc/) on 2018-08-06**:
That was the missing piece of the puzzle. The world tutorials led me astray, thanks for the help. If anyone is curious on where Gazebo looks for model files see here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/177/gazebo-default-directory-and-can-not-insert-model/